# Firewall still blocking port 53 despite listing otherwise?

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, iptables

I have 3 nodes with virtually the same iptables rules loaded from a bash script, but one particular node is blocking traffic on port 53 despite listing it's accepting it:

**$ iptables --list -v**

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 8886 packets, 657K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    2   122 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 
20738 5600K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   any     anywhere             node1.com multiport dports http,smtp 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   any     anywhere             ns.node1.com udp dpt:domain 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   any     anywhere             ns.node1.com tcp dpt:domain 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     node2.backend        anywhere            
   21  1260 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     node3.backend        anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     node4.backend        anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 15804 packets, 26M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**nmap -sV -p 53 ns.node1.com** // From remote server

```
Starting Nmap 4.11 ( http://www.insecure.org/nmap/ ) at 2011-02-24 11:44 EST
Interesting ports on ns.node1.com (1.2.3.4):
PORT   STATE    SERVICE VERSION
53/tcp filtered domain

Nmap finished: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.336 seconds
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that zero packets have actually reached your `iptables` ACCEPT rules for DNS. I think it is likely that your `iptables` rules are specifying an inconsistent combination of conditions that never match incoming DNS queries.

In your case, your DNS ACCEPT rules specify that the incoming interface must be `eth1`, and the destination IP address must resolve to `ns.node1.com`. You should check whether incoming DNS queries to `ns.node1.com` can ever arrive over the `eth1` network interface.

Another possibility is that you have another packet filter somewhere between your test client and your server that is blocking DNS packets.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. The port unblocks when I stop iptables, which rules out a packet filter above my server causing the problem.

Comment: After removing all firewall rules except iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT the port is still blocked. When I stop iptables it's open. Any ideas now?

Comment: @Tom: Clearly, your test packets are not hitting the ACCEPT rule, otherwise the port would not be blocked. The most likely conclusion is that your test packets are not arriving on `eth1`. Are you certain that `eth1` is where they should be arriving?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'll explain my setup - eth0 has the private IP and eth1 has the main IP, eth1:0 is the nameserver (and the desired destination for the packets) and eth1:1 is for nginx. My other 2 servers have identical interfaces and interface aliases. The only difference I can think of is eth1:0 on the other 2 servers are for slave nameservers and eth1:0 on this server is for the master nameserver. Does that provide any insight? Appreciate your help--this is really killing me.

Comment: I should mention, I've always had these standard rules in the bash script before and after the rules to control services: iptables -F; 
iptables -Z; 
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT; 
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT; 
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT; ## rules to control services here ## iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT; 
iptables -P INPUT DROP; 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP;

Comment: @Tom: Consider editing your question when you need to add more info... the comments don't really give much formatting control. Maybe your problem is that the interface named `eth1` doesn't really exist on your server, so no packets match it as an incoming interface. Try removing the in-interface test from your iptables rules, and replace it with a corresponding `--destination <IPaddress>` test.

Comment: Yep, that's it - when I remove the -i eth1 rule and leave in -d the port is open. Any idea why this is? Should I tell my host they've configured the network card incorrectly? Thanks

Comment: Figured it out - interface was down despite being listed as up in ifconfig. Ugh! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Likely to tcp port is blocked by another firewall. Use tcpdump/Wireshark to debug problem.

From me:

```
nmap -sV -p 53 x.x.x.x

Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-02-25 02:32 YEKT
Interesting ports on x.x.x.x:
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
53/tcp open  domain  ISC BIND Not available
```

Comment: When I stop iptables the port becomes open.